# How to add global plugins in Cypress 10

Tags: vue.js, cypress, vuelidate

I am trying to test a login form that uses Vuelidate, and I want to add Vuelidate as a global plugin so I don't have to import it in each test case. I have tried adding it as a global plugin like so:

```
// commands.js
import Vuelidate from "vuelidate";

Cypress.Commands.add('mount', (component, options) => {
  /* Add any global plugins */
  options.global.plugins.push({
    install(app) {
      app.use(Vuelidate);
    },
  });

  return mount(component, options);
})
```

However, when I run my tests, I get an error

[image: Vuelidate cypress test error]

because the inputs of the form have `$v.form`, and `$v` is an instance of Vuelidate. How can I correctly add Vuelidate as a global plugin in my tests?

Currently, it works when I do it per test case like so:

```
// login.cy.js

import { LulaLoginForm } from "lula-components";
import localVue from "vue";
import Vuelidate from 'vuelidate';

localVue.use(Vuelidate)

describe('Login Page', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
        cy.mount(LulaLoginForm, localVue);
  })
})
```

According to the [docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/mount#Creating-a-New-cy-mount-Command). I Should be able to add global plugins. I am using Vue 2.6.14, Vuelidate 0.7.7 and Cypress 11.0.0

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working by importing the apps entry point in `cypress/support/components.js` file.

```
import { mount } from "cypress/vue2";

import "../../src/main.js";

Cypress.Commands.add("mount", mount);
```

I think this is better, considering all the plugins and packages I use in the app, instead of importing them again individually for the tests.